# MAAS on Openstack Autopilot not importing images

Tags: maas, openstack-autopilot

Following the instructions here:  https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud#instructions

Step 3.  Images never start to import although I can see them in the webUI which indicates that it found them remotely.

Several mentions of this issue in other posts, but o one seems to have answered it. Is there a log file someplace that I can view to see what the issue is?  -- nothing in the webUI.

Also , several mentions of a cli tool that apparently is different than the version I have...

maas local boot-resources import
usage: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maascli/**main**.py [-h] COMMAND ...

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

drill down:
  COMMAND
    list      List remote APIs that have been logged-in to.
    login     Log in to a remote API, and remember its description and
              credentials.
    logout    Log out of a remote API, purging any stored credentials.
    refresh   Refresh the API descriptions of all profiles.

http://maas.ubuntu.com/

argument COMMAND: invalid choice: u'local' (choose from u'list', u'login', u'logout', u'refresh')

Has anyone got this working?  -- appreciate a pointer.

-Steve

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, after `sudo apt-get update`, rebooting, and a long wait, it started to work, importing the images.

Comment: Hi @jacksonp2008 you are welcome to mark your own answer as the correct answer :).

Comment: I see no way to do that or I would.

Comment: I think you have to wait a couple of hours before you can be able to mark your own answer as correct.